# Apple Numbers - How to simplify this formula

Tags: numbers

I have a spreadsheet with `Date`, `Amount`, and `Description` from my Bank.

I try to make it categorize automatically the stores I visit most often, so I don't have to do this manually.

In column `Store`, I want to get the Store name based on the `Description` of this transaction, as in the table below.

| Transactions |
| --- |

| Date | Amount | Description | Store | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-19 | 100 | KRA TESCO 01 | Tesco | Groceries |
| 2023-10-18 | 50 | WR Auchan 05 | Auchan | Groceries |
| 2023-10-17 | 70 | McDonalds 65 | McDonalds | Food |
| 2023-10-16 | 30 | KFC PL | KFC | Food |
| 2023-10-15 | 50 | WR TESCO 15 | Tesco | Groceries |
| 2023-10-14 | 24 | BP 01 | BP | Car |
| 2023-10-13 | 56 | Shell 45 | Shell | Car |
| 2023-10-13 | 56 | Shell 45 | Shell | Car |
| 2023-10-13 | 70 | US Walmart 32 | Walmart | Groceries |
| 2023-10-11 | 95 | US Walmart 15 | Walmart | Groceries |
| 2023-10-09 | 42 | Chevron 23 | Chevron | Car |

Below are my current formulas:

Column D ("Store"):

> IFS(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Tesco";Description;start-pos)));"Tesco";NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Auchan";Description;start-pos)));"Auchan";NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Walmart";Description;start-pos)));"Walmart";NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("McDonalds";Description;start-pos)));"McDonalds";NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("KFC";Description;start-pos)));"KFC";NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("BP";Description;start-pos)));"BP";NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Shell";Description;start-pos)));"Shell";NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Chevron";Description;start-pos)));"Chevron")

Colum E ("Category"):

> IFS(OR(Store="TESCO";Store="Auchan";Store="Walmart");"Groceries";OR(Store="KFC";Store="McDonalds");"Food";OR(Store="BP"; Store="Shell"; Store="Chevron"); "Car")

How can I simplify these formulas (mostly the first formula)?

The first formula is basically the repetition of `NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(“Store-Name”;Description;start-pos)))` (which returns TRUE if "Store-Name" is found or FALSE if "Store-Name" is not found) for each Store. How could I simplify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one way of simplifying them would be to use a second table as a small database combined with the REGEX.EXTRACT function for the first one and the XLOOKUP function for the second one as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

In the screenshot, the formula  starting with IFERROR shows the one in D12 and the formula starting with XLOOKUP shows the one in E12. Also find below the same formulas in text:

| Cell | Formula |
| --- | --- |
| D12 | `=IFERROR(REGEX.EXTRACT(UPPER(Description '2023-10-09');"\b"&TEXTJOIN("|";1;Stores::Store)&"\b";1);"-")` |
| E12 | `=XLOOKUP(Store '2023-10-09';Stores::Store;Stores::Category;"-";0)` |

P.S. If you are not familiar with the regex functions in Numbers, one of the places to start learning about them would be [this excellent video](https://youtu.be/WwszQEDmTLw?si=W8o4Hu9TxvQ9ariv) introducing them by Gary Rosenzweig of macmost.com.

Comment: This works, thank you! And thanks for providing the video too.